# In series 5 final the big bang how did the doctor get out of the pandorica?

Tags: doctor-who

I was wondering in the grand final of series 5 the big bang how ever did the Doctor manage to get out of the pandorica as it has never come up. I've also tried looking it up in My Doctor who encyclopedia but had no luck finding anything

Comment: You Fell Victim to one of the Classic Blunders!  The most famous of which is "never get involved in a land war in Asia" - but only slightly less well-known is this: "never think that causation is an unescapable obstacle to a time traveller"

Comment: It's an ontological paradox, a.k.a. a "Moffat Loop". Other examples of this kind of thing is the episode Blink. It has no clear beginning or end, but it's consistent.

Answer (score 0):

He never get out because the Pandorica and the Doctor never existed.
When he restart the universe, he was left behind, erased from time and space, like falling into a Space-Time Crack: he make the Universe a re-start leaving him behindl leaving him as a story in Amy's subconscius.